# How can I customize the style of the autogenerated columns of a GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a **GridView** and I need to be able to **set the style for the autogenerated columns,** particularly I will need to set the **width** of each column. How can I do that?

Thanks for replies!

**SOLUTION UPDATE:**

(thanks to Stephan Bauer)

Add event on DataGrid

```
OnDataBound="ItemsBound"
```

In the event set the width:

```
protected void ItemsBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    (sender as GridView).Rows[0].Cells[0].Width = Unit.Pixel(150);
}
```

Or you can do:

```
(sender as GridView).Rows[0].Cells[0].Style.Add("width", "150px");
```

to set any other css property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use GridView's `Columns` property in DataBound event because the generated columns are not added to the GridView's `Columns` collection if the GridView's `AutoGenerateColumns` property is set to `true`.

But you could try manipulating the properties of  `myGrid.Row[x].Cells[y]` (Remember to check if the specified row and cell exist):

```
protected void myGrid_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
  this.myGrid.Row[0].Cells[0].Width = Unit.Pixel(500);
}
```

Comment: Could you give an example please? How can I access the columns in that event?

Comment: Using (sender as System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView).Columns.Count returns a Count of 0. Any idea how does it work?

Comment: Nice, your solution works. I eventually used the code inside OnDataBound cause I only need to set width once for it to work.

Comment: Change code to OnDataBound so I can tick it as answer, cause it's more efficient that way. I gave example in my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the various style properties e.g.

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" RowStyle-BackColor="AliceBlue" RowStyle-CssClass="SomeClassThatSetsTheColumnWidth" />
```

This works whether the columns are autogenerated or not.

Comment: Yes, but I need to customize each column individually. For example one needs to have a width of 80pixels, another has to have 150pixels etc.

Comment: If you have specific size for specific columns then why are you using autogenerated columns?

Comment: You have a pretty good point :) I am studying how to do paging and sorting and I was curious if setting the width for autogenerated columns was possible.

Comment: Auto generated columns are not very useful in production, I use them mainly for rapid prototyping.  If you have unpredictable numbers of columns or column names from your data source you might use them but that is kind of an edge case.

Answer (score -1):

It Works ..thanks 
I need to apply the header style on autogenrated columns. Below is the code for applying header css on Autogenrated columns

```
protected void grvRequirement_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.grv_RequirementList.HeaderRow.CssClass = "grid_sub_heading";
}
```

And Stephen there is a mistake and it should be like this

this.myGrid.Rows[0].Cells[0].Width = Unit.Pixel(500);